# Do a loop with letters in R

Tags: r

I want to do a loop with letter..i have a matrix(named 'a') and i want to have all the column names..

```
k<-arrayInd(2,dim(a))
colnames(a)[k[,1]]
colnames(a)[k[,2]]
colnames(a)[k[,3]]
.
.
.
colnames(a)[k[,n]]
```

i guess the loop will be something like that

```
aa<-list()
for (i in 1:n) {
aa[[i]]<-colnames(a)[k[,i]]
}
```

But i don't get any results. I think that the loop is ok but i have to change with something else the

```
aa<-list()
```

and replace the "list" with something else..

Comment: assign to each element of list in loop `aa[[i]] <- colnames(a)[k[,i]] ` I am not sure what you are trying to do though. A reproducible example would be better

Comment: try `as.list(colnames(a))`

Comment: try `vector` (and use single brackets) maybe?

Comment: also if you provided a reproducible example you'd get more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a matrix `mat`, which looks like this:

```
mat <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(letters[1:2], LETTERS[1:2]))
```

You can inspect its structure like this:

```
str(mat)
# int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
# ..$ : chr [1:2] "A" "B"
```

And you get the column names by using this:

```
colnames(mat)
# [1] "A" "B"
```

Comment: @vasilis If it works, you can check the answer so it's marked as "solved".